# Exclude traffic coming from a specific landing page in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to exclude visitors who came to the site from a specific landing page. Is it possible to do this with GTM? There is an option to create an Audience in GA4, but I would like to permanently delete this traffic and not exclude this Audience every time during analysis.

In GA4 it is possible to filter traffic only by IP addresses. And in GTM I know the option to exclude pages with certain URLs or parameters. But I would like to exclude traffic coming from a specific landing page.